# regular expression pattern doesn't match

Tags: java, regex

I have some html codes saved in a file. I want to replace all texts that match this pattern: `@@[\w]{1,}@@`. but why this pattern in my java code doesn't work? is my pattern wrong?

```
String line = "\t<title>@@title@@</title>";

if(line.matches("@@title@@")) {
    line = line.replaceAll("@@title@@", "Title");
}
```

Comment: Counsel: do not parse HTML with regexes. Use HTML parsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
line.matches("@@title@@")
```

means the whole line matches. Imagine it like this

```
line.matches("^@@title@@$")
```

And `replaceAll` won't throw exception if there is no match, so you can simply drop your check:

```
String line = "\t<title>@@title@@</title>";
line = line.replaceAll("@@title@@", "Title");
```

Comment: how to prevent it from comparing the pattern with whole line?

Comment: @user88731 Use `java.util.regex` package.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, [String#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) only returns true if the **whole** string matches the regex. In your case you want this regex: `.*@@title@@.*`.

I think [String#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) is better for your case since you are not really want to match a regex but a substring.